# HTML elements I add in Google Drive don't work

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, google-chrome-extension, html-select

I created a chrome extension which activates when I enter in an specified folder in Google Drive. This extension adds a diagram made with D3.js in that folder as you can see in the following picture:

[image]

[image]

Apart from the diagram, it also adds a dropdown list but the problem is that it doesn't work when I click on it (it doesn't show the options). The only thing it does is to create the rectangle to select elements as you can see in the next picture:
[image]

I tried to add other HTML elements in Google Drive such as buttons but they didn't work either. It seems that Google Drive deactivate the onclick event of the html elements I add.

The code of the dropdown list:

```
d3.select("#divSelect")
    .append("select")
    .attr("class","desplegable")
    .attr("id","desplegable")
    .on('change',function (d,i) {
        var grupoSeleccionado = d3.select("#desplegable").node().value; //Examen seleccionado
        if (grupoSeleccionado=="Total"){ //Vision general de los examenes
            dibujarSpiderChart(data);

        } else { //Vision de un examen en concreto
            var notasAlumnoExamen=_.filter(data[0],{'group':grupoSeleccionado});
            var notasMediasExamen=_.filter(data[1],{'group':grupoSeleccionado});
            var dataGrupo=[];
            dataGrupo.push(notasAlumnoExamen);
            dataGrupo.push(notasMediasExamen);
            dibujarSpiderChart(dataGrupo);
        }
        ;})
    .selectAll("option")
    .data(gruposLista)
    .enter()
    .append("option")
    .attr("value", function (d) { return d.id; })
    .text(function (d) { return d.nombre; });
```

Comment: Can you show us how you attached your event listener to the HTML dropdown?

Comment: There's likely some CSS or JavaScript running for Google Drive that replaces the `select` with something else that messes with yours. I'm not terribly familiar with Chrome extensions, but maybe there's a way of injecting custom CSS for your `select` to override that?

Comment: I also think that Google Drive is changing my Select with some CSS or JavaScript. I injected custom CSS to my Select but It is still not working and I don´t know how to resolve the problem or what other alternatives consider. I need that dropdown list.